# Expect script that enters a username and password repeatedly

Tags: regex, svn, git, ssh, expect

I have a script that needs to switch between various branches in my subversion repository in order to do a copy. This results in having to enter the password repeatedly. Now, once I have done this a couple of time and i am well into my script. I mess up causing me great anger.

I have used expect to enter a password on a prompt before. I was hoping to learn how to get expect to run over multiple password prompts again and again and again, until the task is finished.

So far this is what I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
global env
set timeout 10
spawn command that requires password
expect "^user"
send "password\r"
#i need this to repeat over and over until the prompt stops showing up.
```

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naive, brute force method:

```
while 1 {
    expect $prompt
    send $password\r
}
```

Better:

```
expect {
    $prompt {
        send $password\r
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout {
        puts "haven't seen prompt for $timeout seconds"
    }
    "some pattern that indicates password no longer required"
}
puts "continuing ..."
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about using [ssh keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) so you don't have to type the password over and over again?

Comment: ssh keys dont work, I have them setup but it doesn't want to check them, when i am running this command.

Comment: In my opinion, getting that fixed is much more beneficial than getting this script to work. Why don't you to ask that question instead. It should work if you have set up everything correctly. I do this will all my server and life is so much easier.